# D3 pack layout with variable padding

Tags: javascript, d3.js, pack

I am not able to get variable padding using d3.layout.pack().padding().
I want to put different padding at group and at leaf nodes.

```
d3.layout.pack()
.sort(null)
.size([this.width , this.height])
.children(function (d) {
    return d.values;
})
.value(function (d){
    return 1;
})
.padding(function (d){
    return d.padding;
})
.nodes({
    values: outerClusterData
})


// Sample data 
outerClusterData = [
    {
        key: "africa",
        padding: 100,
        values: [
            {
                name: "city1",
                padding: 10
            },
            {
                name: "city2",
                padding: 10 
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        key: "India",
        padding: 100,
        values: [
            {
                name: "city3",
                padding: 10
            },
            {
                name: "city4",
                padding: 10 
            }
        ] 
    }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the structure as following:

```
<svg>
 <g class="content-group">
</svg>
```

Step 1: Set the minimum radius using radius accessor to some constant value.

Step 2: After Step 1, The grouped circle will be quiet large, as radius of
the grouped circle is padding + space occupied by inner circles

Step 3: Set ViewPort using height and width, using height and width attribute, Once the content is drawn, Get the bounding box of g.content-group, using d3.select('g.content-group').node().bbox(), This will give you x,y,height,width. Which can be used to set the attributes of viewbox = "x y width height"

Lets the viewport be widthVP * heightVP, and viewBox be "x y width height", Then the new coordinate system will have unit which will be equal to widthVP/width in x direction and  heightVP/height in y direction.