# d3 function (d) not being called

Tags: javascript, d3.js

It's my first time using d3, and I'm trying to dynamically increase the padding for circles in a D3 packing chart, using the below function:

```
var pack = d3.layout.pack()
        .padding(function(d) {
              console.log(d.padding);
              return d.padding;
          })
        .size([diameter, diameter])
        .value(100),
        arc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(0),
        pie = d3.layout.pie;
```

The function in the padding parameter above does not run, and instead padding is defaulted to 0. When I place the function in `.value()` however, it runs correctly and logs `d.padding` to the console as expected. Why is this function not running in the padding parameter but runs fine in the value parameter?

Possibly related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50470731/d3-pack-layout-with-variable-padding) question.

Comment: Well, in D3 **v3** [`pack.padding()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Pack-Layout.md#padding) did not support passing a function... This was introduced by v4.

Comment: Thanks thats makes sense, out of curiosity would it be much of a bother to transfer a 500+ line script from v3 to v4?